# combining regex and embedded objects in mongodb queries

Tags: regex, mongodb, embedded-object

I am trying to combine regex and embedded object queries and failing miserably. I am either hitting a limitation of mongodb or just getting something slightly wrong maybe someone out ther has encountered this. The documentation certainly does'nt cover this case.

data being queried:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f94fe633004c1ef4d892314"),
    "productname" : "lightbulb",
    "availability" : [
            {
                    "country" : "USA",
                    "storeCode" : "abc-1234"
            },
            {
                    "country" : "USA",
                    "storeCode" : "xzy-6784"
            },
            {
                    "country" : "USA",
                    "storeCode" : "abc-3454"
            },
            {
                    "country" : "CANADA",
                    "storeCode" : "abc-6845"
            }
    ]
}
```

assume the collection contains only one record

This query returns 1:

```
db.testCol.find({"availability":{"country" : "USA","storeCode":"xzy-6784"}}).count();
```

This query returns 1:

```
db.testCol.find({"availability.storeCode":/.*/}).count();
```

**But, this query returns 0**:

```
db.testCol.find({"availability":{"country" : "USA","storeCode":/.*/}}).count();
```

Does anyone understand why? Is this a bug?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing the embedded storecode incorrectly - you are referencing it as an embedded object when in fact what you have is an **array** of objects.  Compare these results:

```
db.testCol.find({"availability.0.storeCode":/x/});
db.testCol.find({"availability.0.storeCode":/a/});
```

Using your sample doc above, the first one will not return, because the first storeCode does not have an x in it ("abc-1234"), the second will return the document.  That's fine for the case where you are looking at a single element of the array and pass in the position.  In order to search all of the objcts in the array, you want [$elemMatch](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29#DotNotation%28ReachingintoObjects%29-Matchingwith%24elemMatch)

As an example, I added this second example doc:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f94fe633004c1ef4d892315"),
    "productname" : "hammer",
    "availability" : [
            {
                    "country" : "USA",
                    "storeCode" : "abc-1234"
            },

    ]
}
```

Now, have a look at the results of these queries:

```
PRIMARY> db.testCol.find({"availability" : {$elemMatch : {"storeCode":/a/}}}).count();
2
PRIMARY> db.testCol.find({"availability" : {$elemMatch : {"storeCode":/x/}}}).count();
1
```

Comment: thank you. That did the trick and I understand mongodb a bit better now.